# react-selectize How to give floting label text

Tags: reactjs

In react-selectize dropdown list is not comming. So please help me how to display the dropdown list.

```
var options = ["Idea", "Airtel", "Vodaphone", "Docomo", "Aircel"].map(function(provider){
     return {label: provider, value: provider}
 });
 <SimpleSelect
    options = {options}
  placeholder = "Select a fruit"
 theme = "material" 

  style={{
    'width': '100%',
'marginTop': '10px',
   'fontSize': '16px'
     }}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleSelect` requires you to declare options like this ([example on the react-selectize github page](https://github.com/furqanZafar/react-selectize#usage-jsx)) :

```
<SimpleSelect placeholder="Select a fruit" onValueChange={value => alert(value)}>
  <option value = "apple">apple</option>
  <option value = "mango">mango</option>
  <option value = "orange">orange</option>
  <option value = "banana">banana</option>
</SimpleSelect>
```

To pass options as props instead, use `MultiSelect`:

```
var options = ["Idea", "Airtel", "Vodaphone", "Docomo", "Aircel"].map(function(provider){
     return {label: provider, value: provider}
});

<MultiSelect
  options = {options}
  placeholder = "Select a fruit"
  theme = "material" 
  style={{
    'width': '100%',
    'marginTop': '10px',
    'fontSize': '16px'
  }}
/>
```